# Springboot app gives error after starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml

I wrote a springboot application but it gives error before run method execution.I observed with debug it enters main method but after that it gives error immediately.I checked pom.xml file but I did not find any problem with dependencies.

Error is : `org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z`

Do you have any idea?

My app class is :

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProcessesApplication implements CommandLineRunner {    

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessesApplication.class);

@Autowired
private BatchManager batchManager;



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ProcessesApplication.class, args);

}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    Integer threadCount = 5;        
    try {        
        if (args.length > 1 && args[1] != null && !args[1].trim().isEmpty()) {
            try {
                threadCount = Integer.valueOf(args[1].trim());
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
       
        this.batchManager.setThreadCount(threadCount);
        this.batchManager.setProcessName("Process");
        this.batchManager.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace(e);
    }
}
```

}

My pom.xml is

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.App</groupId>
<artifactId>processes</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<name>processes</name>
<description>data sending </description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>      
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Log file :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
at org.springframework.context.event.GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.supportsSourceType(GenericApplicationListenerAdapter.java:81)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.supportsEvent(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:304)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:225)
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:196)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
at com.App.processes.ProcessesApplication.main(ProcessesApplication.java:39)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@Configuration` annotation

Comment: I added my log file.

Comment: I found the solution.My eclipse contains 4 different project.One of them gives this error.I deleted this project after that my application is running.My pom.xml contains that jar but when i want to import that project eclipse gives that error.Actually it is a temporary solution

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest seperating the class with `main()` function from the other class.

Basically create a class that has only the `main()` function inside and another class for the `CommandLineRunner`.

Example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class SpringApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

And a seperate Class for the `Runner`:

```java
@Component
public class ARunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception
    {
        // Your code...
    }
}
```